# List <t> dont appear on listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have this list on my form

```
public static List<addbb> ref = new List<addbb> ();
```

Im using this to add items on list

```
Form1.ref.Add(new addbb(1a + "; "+2a+"; "+3a+".", 4a);
```

im bing to listbox

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = ref;
```

But when load, appear this

[image]

Already I tried to use the toArray more the result and the same

Comment: Side note: Please, don't use reserved keywords - `ref` in this case - as variable names

Answer (score 1):

You should override ToString() method on your type:

```
public class addbb
{
     public override string ToString() => "your output";
}
```

Comment: Really thanks man, works great...